# How to extract two consecutive lines that match pattern in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract lines that match two different patterns from `test.txt`.
First I want to extract line that match `>> fbat -v1` and then match the corresponding line just below `p-value(2-sided)`.

This is the code I tried, but it only extracts the first match.

```
import re

file = open('test.txt')
for line in file:
    match = re.findall('^>> fbat -v1', line)
    if match:
        print line
```

I also tried to do this in R, but seems like R is not well suited to do this. I am not familiar with python, so can someone please help me with the solution.
Thank you in advance.

test.txt:

```
>> fbat -v1 1:939467:A:G
trait STATUS; offset 0.150; model additive; test bi-allelic; minsize 2; min_freq 0.000; p 1.000; maxcmh 1000

Marker            afreq     fam#       weight     S-E(S)      Var(S)      Z        P
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Weighted FBAT rare variant statistics for the SNPs:

W           Var(W)      Z           p-value(2-sided)
----------------------------------------------------
0.400       0.240       0.816       4.14216178e-01
----------------------------------------------------


>> fbat -v1 1:941298:C:T 1:941301:G:A 1:941310:C:T 1:941324:G:A
trait STATUS; offset 0.150; model additive; test bi-allelic; minsize 2; min_freq 0.000; p 1.000; maxcmh 1000

Marker            afreq     fam#       weight     S-E(S)      Var(S)      Z        P
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Weighted FBAT rare variant statistics for the SNPs:

W           Var(W)      Z           p-value(2-sided)
----------------------------------------------------
0.333       0.444       0.500       6.17075077e-01
----------------------------------------------------
```

Result :

```
>> fbat -v1 1:939467:A:G 0.400       0.240       0.816       4.14216178e-01
>> fbat -v1 1:941298:C:T 1:941301:G:A 1:941310:C:T 1:941324:G:A 0.333       0.444       0.500       6.17075077e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression that picks the data you want out of multiple lines. With only two samples it's hard to know if this one will match all cases: some of your data might not be as regular as the samples suggest.

This does not follow the line-at-a-time pattern of `for line in file:` because your data consists of bunches of lines.

```
file = open('test.txt')
data = file.read()
rex = re.compile(r"(>> fbat -v1.+?\n).+?p-value\(2-sided\)\n-+\n(.+?)\n-", re.DOTALL)
for header, numbers in rex.findall(data):
    print (header.rstrip(), numbers)
```

Output is

```
>> fbat -v1 1:939467:A:G 0.400       0.240       0.816       4.14216178e-01
>> fbat -v1 1:941298:C:T 1:941301:G:A 1:941310:C:T 1:941324:G:A 0.333       0.444       0.500       6.17075077e-01
```

I note in passing that you are working in Python 2. Unless this is a one-off, please consider switching to Python 3. You should not be investing time in learning Python 2.

Comment: Why am I getting this error: 
  `File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'data' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, cut'n'paste error. You got a syntax error in the `read()` call and so `data` did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

file = open('test.txt')
for idx, line in enumerate(file):
    match = re.findall('^>> fbat -v1', line)
    if match:
        match = re.findall('p-value(2-sided)', file[idx+1])
```

Of course, you would need to take care of the last row, since if it matches `^>> fbat -v1`, you are trying to access the next row which does not exist.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting `TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
`

Comment: Can be improved by using a context manager to handle the file object.

Comment: @S3DEV A context manager won't fix the last line, that treats a file object as if it were a list.

Comment: @BoarGules - Agreed, I didn’t mention it would.  The comment addresses how to better handle the file object itself.

Comment: @S3DEV There is little point in prettifying broken code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use regex, you can make use of generator that allows you to reduce RAM usage if you read a very large amount of data (and 10GB large file)

```py
f = open("input.txt")

# you can replace f.readline() by string.splitlines()  by string_to_parse.splitlines() or f.readlines()
content = (line.replace("\n", "") for line in f.readlines())
result = []
try:
    # you can replace content by string.splitlines() if you read from a file
    for line in content: 
        #We try to find a line that starts with >> fbat -v1 
        if line.startswith(">> fbat -v1"):
            result_line = line
            # Jump lines until we find the one that ends with p-value(2-sided)
            while not next(content).endswith("p-value(2-sided)"):
                pass
            # jump one line to ignore the ----------------------------------------------------
            next(content) 
            # We add the line to our result
            result_line += next(content)
            # finally we add our result to a list 
            result.append(result_line) 
# this will happen if there is a >> fbat -v1 without p-value(2-sided) after
except StopIteration: 
    print('Could not find "p-value(2-sided)" after ">> fbat -v1" ')

# print the result
print("\n".join(result))
```

I used here a file to contain the data (if it is a log file)